# JEST - check if objects array is a subset of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jestjs

Using JEST I want to test if an array of objects is a subset of another array.

I want to test the following:

```
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Hugo'}, {id: 2, name: 'Francesco'}, {id: 3, name: 'Carlo'}];
const subset = [{id: 1, name: 'Hugo'}, {id: 2, name: 'Francesco'}];

expect(users).toContain(subset)
```

I've tried the following:

```
describe('test 1', () => {
  it('test 1', () => {
    expect(users).toEqual(
      expect.arrayContaining([
        expect.objectContaining(subset)
      ])
    )
  });
});
```

But this is not correct since *objectContaining* doesn't accept array as param ... it works only if subset is a single object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never tried this myself, but wouldn't it work to just say:

```
expect(users).toEqual(
  expect.arrayContaining(subset)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.. but this line was causing you the trouble `expect.objectContaining(subset)` where you are supposed to pass an object instead of an array.

As @instanceof mentioned, below code would work.. but let me  share the details like what's happening here

```
expect(users).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining(subset)
)
```

In the above snippet, `expect.arrayContaining(subset)` matches a received array which contains all of the elements in the expected array. That is, the expected array is a subset of the received array.

Please note that even if you are checking for a single element, you need to pass it as an array to `arrayContaining()` method

Same applies for `objectContaining()` as well.. let's say if you want to check an Array contains an object, you can test it something like this

```
expect(users).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([ // Note that it should be an array
        expect.objectContaining({ // Note that it should be an object
            id: 123,
        });
    ]);
);
```

Hope this helps :)